# Springboot jaxws (cxf) issue

Tags: spring-boot, cxf

I am unable to run spring-boot with apache cxf project.
I tried with spring boot 1.5.3 & 1.4.4 along with cxf version 3.1.10/3.1.11

my entries:

```
  <parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
```

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ServletRegistrationBean when I use 1.5.4       could not load extension class AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl when I use 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot 1.5+, please use cxf 3.1.11, refer this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7198) for more info